# Acrlong as first time use flag

Tags: glossaries

Is there a way to have `glossaries` identify `\acrshort{foo}` as the first time use (if it is indeed the first time it is used), so that following `\gls{foo}`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newacronym{a}{foo}{Foo foo foo}

\begin{document}
    I would like for this acronym, \acrlong{a} (\acrshort{a}, something to say about it), to count as first time use, so I can do \gls{a} for the rest of the text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to automatically unset the glossary entry when using `\acrshort`. This can be achieved by adding

```
\makeatletter
  \pretocmd\@acrshort{\glsunset{#2}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

to your preamble.

Comment: Yup, just what I needed!